# Why can't I define this rewrite rule for type elimination of proof-irrelevant disjunctions in Agda

Tags: agda, dependent-type, type-theory

I'm attempting to axiomatize a proof-irrelevant disjunction proposition with type elimination in Agda using the [universe of proof-irrelevant propositions](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.2.2/language/prop.html). However, when I attempt to define rewrite rules for the computation rules I get an error about a certain variable not being bound. For instance, taking a minimal example, the following code does not compile:

```
{-# OPTIONS --rewriting --prop #-}

open import Agda.Builtin.Equality
open import Agda.Builtin.Equality.Rewrite

module Disjunction where

private variable
  α β : Prop
  A : Set

postulate
  _∨_ : (α : Prop) (β : Prop) → Prop

  inl : α → α ∨ β
  inr : β → α ∨ β
  ∨-rec : (a₁ : α → A) (a₂ : β → A) → ((x : α) (y : β) → a₁ x ≡ a₂ y) → α ∨ β → A
  ∨-rec-inl : {a₁ : α → A} {a₂ : β → A} {h : (x : α) (y : β) → a₁ x ≡ a₂ y} {x : α} → ∨-rec a₁ a₂ h (inl x) ≡ a₁ x

{-# REWRITE ∨-rec-inl #-}
```

and gives me the error

> ```
> ∨-rec-inl  is not a legal rewrite rule, since the following variables are not bound by the left hand side:  x
> ```

However, this error no longer occurs when I change `α ∨ β` to be a type (i.e. a term of `Set`) instead of a proof-irrelevant proposition. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to apply the rewrite rule, Agda needs to infer the value of `x`, i.e. it needs to match the fourth argument to the pattern `inl x`. However, if this argument is made irrelevant, then it is not allowed for Agda to inspect it (since this would refute the irrelevance) hence Agda rejects the rule.

Comment: Ah, yes, of course! So the best I can do to be able to define the appropriate rewrite rules is to use a propositionally truncated disjunction in `Set`?